# Passing values between Thread Groups in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

How to pass values that generated in one thread group into another thread group?

Ex:-Random 10 numbers generating in my 1st thread group i want to pass that generated 10 numbers to my second and third thread groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can. [follow the steps as mentioned here.](https://kishorsharma69.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/absolute-directory-path-for-jmx-file-jmeter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. In 1st Thread Group you can use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to set some value. In 2nd Thread Group you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to refer the value, set in the 1st Thread Group

   [image: JMeter Pass Values Between Thread Groups]

   See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for more detailed explanation if you need it.
2. If you need not only to pass the values, but set up some form of synchronization - go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) which is capable of passing values between JMeter threads (even residing in different Thread Groups) via some form of FIFO queue.

   You can install the plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)